# loop, iterate with unexpected result

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

i have to make a loop but i tried so many time to get a expected result, but i have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class JavaApplication34 {
   int totalResults = 248; //
   int itemsperPage = 10;
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   int count = 0;

   public void makeLoop() {
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         System.out.println("nextPage " + i);
         this.count = i + 1;
         for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.println("Filenummer " + (j + 1));
            this.count = j + 1;
            System.out.println("count " + count);
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JavaApplication34 myTest = new JavaApplication34();
      myTest.makeLoop();
   }        
}
```

i should get on the console following result

- page 1, filenummer 1, filenummer 2, filenummer 3...,filenummer 10
- page 2, filenummer 11, filenummer 12, filenummer 13...,filenummer20
- page 3 , and so on

Comment: And what result are you in fact seeing?

Comment: Is this line right? `page 2, filenummer 11, filenummer 3, filenummer...,filenummer20` I would except you want `page 2, filenummer 11, filenummer 12, filenummer...,filenummer20`

Comment: your expected answer seems weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the expected output you could change you code too

```
for (i = 1; i <= (totalResults/itemsperPage) + 1; i++) {
    System.out.println("nextPage " + i);
    for (; j < i* itemsperPage; j++) {
        if(j > totalResults) {
           break;
        }
        System.out.println("Filenummer " + (j + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: but it gives me only 90 Files out, but it should be 100,

Comment: totalResults is the count of Filenumbers, it should be, if totalResults is 100, 100 Filenumbeers

Comment: totalResults will be in the Future dynamically

Comment: could you show how? totalResults wich i do get evrytime an other number and not Fixed to 10, how to handle?, please

Comment: I tried your new code, if you give totalResults the value=55, it prints out to 50, not to 55, or 148 it prints out 140, but it works fine with 10, 20, 30, and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61174/discussion-between-maurice-merlin-and-aeshang).

Answer (score 1):

i have now the following code,  aeshang wrote:

public class JavaApplication34 {

```
int totalResults = 34;
int itemsperPage = 10;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

public void makeLoop() {

    for (i = 1; i <= (totalResults / itemsperPage); i++) {
        System.out.println("nextPage " + i);
        for (; j < i * itemsperPage; j++) {
            if (j > totalResults) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Filenummer " + (j + 1));
        }
    }

}
```

it gives me the following output

- nexpage 1, filenumber 1, filnumber 2, ...., filnumber 10
- nexpage 2, filenumber 11,filenumber 12...., filnumber 20
- ...........
- nexpage 3, filenumber 21, filenumber 22, ...filnumber 30 ( but it
  should be till, 34)

Comment: hi aeshang i hope you will find out, how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int totalResults = 34;
        int itemsperPage = 10;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int loopSize = (totalResults / itemsperPage);

        public void makeLoop() {
            loopSize = (totalResults % itemsperPage > 0) ? ++loopSize : loopSize;

            for (i = 1; i <= loopSize; i++) {
                System.out.print("nextPage " + i + "...");
                for (; j < i * itemsperPage; j++) {
                    if (j > totalResults) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.print(" Filenummer " + (j + 1));
                }
                System.out.println();

            }

        }
```

Output=
nextPage 1... Filenummer 1 Filenummer 2 Filenummer 3 Filenummer 4 Filenummer 5 Filenummer 6 Filenummer 7 Filenummer 8 Filenummer 9 Filenummer 10
nextPage 2... Filenummer 11 Filenummer 12 Filenummer 13 Filenummer 14 Filenummer 15 Filenummer 16 Filenummer 17 Filenummer 18 Filenummer 19 Filenummer 20
nextPage 3... Filenummer 21 Filenummer 22 Filenummer 23 Filenummer 24 Filenummer 25 Filenummer 26 Filenummer 27 Filenummer 28 Filenummer 29 Filenummer 30
nextPage 4... Filenummer 31 Filenummer 32 Filenummer 33 Filenummer 34 Filenummer 35

Comment: it should be have 34 items, this gives back 35?

Answer (score 0):

```
int totalResults = 34;
int itemsperPage = 10;
int i = 0;
int j = 1;
int loopSize = (totalResults / itemsperPage);

public void makeLoop() {
    loopSize = (totalResults % itemsperPage > 0) ? ++loopSize : loopSize;

    for (i = 1; i <= loopSize; i++) {
        System.out.print("nextPage " + i + "...");
        for (; j < i * itemsperPage; j++) {
            if (j > totalResults) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.print(" Filenummer " + (j));
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

output=
nextPage 1... Filenummer 1 Filenummer 2 Filenummer 3 Filenummer 4 Filenummer 5 Filenummer 6 Filenummer 7 Filenummer 8 Filenummer 9
nextPage 2... Filenummer 10 Filenummer 11 Filenummer 12 Filenummer 13 Filenummer 14 Filenummer 15 Filenummer 16 Filenummer 17 Filenummer 18 Filenummer 19
nextPage 3... Filenummer 20 Filenummer 21 Filenummer 22 Filenummer 23 Filenummer 24 Filenummer 25 Filenummer 26 Filenummer 27 Filenummer 28 Filenummer 29
nextPage 4... Filenummer 30 Filenummer 31 Filenummer 32 Filenummer 33 Filenummer 34